How Do I Perform Integer Division on a Balanced Ternary String Using C#?
How do I perform integer division on a Ternary string? I'm trying it using the following example 'C'-like code below - which I got from a University professor's page on Ternary math - I'm unfamiliar with the concept of a double register and how to properly shift it left when emulated by a string - and I don't know what a "long comparison" is either - not sure where I'm going wrong:
balanced int rem, quo; /* the remainder and quotient, return values */
void div( balanced int dividend, balanced int divisor ) {
    quo = dividend;
    rem = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < trits_per_word; i++) {
        /* first shift rem-quo double register 1 trit left */
        (rem,quo) = (rem,quo) <<3 1;

        /* second, compute candidates for next remainder */
    balanced int high = rem + divisor;
    balanced int mid = rem;
    balanced int low = rem - divisor;

    /* pick a candidate, using long comparison */
    (rem,) = closest_to_zero( (high,quo), (mid,quo), (low,quo) );

    /* set the quotiet digit */
        if (rem == high) {
            quo = quo - 1;
    } else if (rem == low) {
        quo = quo + 1;
        }
    }
}

I'm using a string of 3 values (- / 0 / +) to represent balanced ternary and I don't know how to emulate a double register trit-shift or I'm doing something else wrong. I know it may look a little odd but I'm trying to emulate a ternary processor working through strings. My code is below:
public static TernaryIntGeneric DivideTernaryInts(TernaryIntGeneric int1, TernaryIntGeneric int2)
        {
            int fullLength = int1.fullTernaryValue.Length;
            if (fullLength <= PROCESSOR_WIDTH_IN_TRITS)
            {
                if (ComparisonOperator(int2, new TernaryIntGeneric(0)) == '0')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ATTEMPT TO DIVIDE BY ZERO!");
                    return null;
                }
                else if (ComparisonOperator(AbsoluteValue(int1), AbsoluteValue(int2)) == '+')
                {
                    var dividend = int1.integerPartTernaryValue;
                    var quo = dividend;
                    var rem = CreateEmptyTernaryValue(TernaryIntGeneric.NIntegerTrits);
                    var divisor = int2;
                    var one = new TernaryIntGeneric(1);
                    var finalQuotient = new TernaryIntGeneric(0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < TernaryIntGeneric.NIntegerTrits; i++)
                    {
                        string remquo = rem + quo;
                        remquo = TritShiftLeft(remquo, 1);

                        Console.WriteLine(remquo);

                        rem = remquo.Substring(0, TernaryIntGeneric.NIntegerTrits);
                        quo = remquo.Substring(TernaryIntGeneric.NIntegerTrits, TernaryIntGeneric.NIntegerTrits);
                        var remainder = new TernaryIntGeneric(rem);
                        var quotient = new TernaryIntGeneric(quo);

                        Console.WriteLine("Remainder: " + remainder.integerValue);
                        Console.WriteLine("Quotient: " + quotient.integerValue);

                        var high = AddTernaryInts(remainder, divisor);
                        var mid = remainder;
                        var low = SubtractTernaryInts(remainder, divisor);

                        Console.WriteLine("High: " + high.integerValue);
                        Console.WriteLine("Low: " + low.integerValue);

                        if ((ComparisonOperator(AbsoluteValue(SubtractTernaryInts(quotient, high)), AbsoluteValue(SubtractTernaryInts(quotient, low))) == '-') && (ComparisonOperator(AbsoluteValue(SubtractTernaryInts(quotient, high)), AbsoluteValue(SubtractTernaryInts(quotient, mid))) == '-'))
                        {
                            remainder = high;
                            quotient = SubtractTernaryInts(quotient, one);
                            Console.WriteLine("High Chosen");
                            Console.WriteLine("Remainder: " + remainder.integerValue);
                            Console.WriteLine("Quotient: " + quotient.integerValue);
                        }
                        else if ((ComparisonOperator(AbsoluteValue(SubtractTernaryInts(quotient, high)), AbsoluteValue(SubtractTernaryInts(quotient, low))) == '+') && (ComparisonOperator(AbsoluteValue(SubtractTernaryInts(quotient, low)), AbsoluteValue(SubtractTernaryInts(quotient, mid))) == '-'))
                        {
                            remainder = low;
                            quotient = AddTernaryInts(quotient, one);
                            Console.WriteLine("Low Chosen");
                            Console.WriteLine("Remainder: " + remainder.integerValue);
                            Console.WriteLine("Quotient: " + quotient.integerValue);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Mid Chosen");
                            //do nothing, it's mid (0)    
                        }
                        quo = quotient.integerPartTernaryValue;
                        rem = remainder.integerPartTernaryValue;
                        finalQuotient = quotient;
                    }
                    return finalQuotient;

                }
                else if (int1.integerPartTernaryValue == int2.integerPartTernaryValue)
                {
                    return new TernaryIntGeneric(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new TernaryIntGeneric(0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TERNARY INTEGER TOO LONG FOR PROCESSOR WIDTH");
                return null;
            }
        }

The ComparisonOperator returns - if left is less, + if left is more, and 0 if equal. TritShiftLeft shifts the string of characters to the left by a given number and fills in the empty space with 0's. The test code and output is the following:
var num10 = TernaryCPU.DivideTernaryInts(new TernaryIntGeneric(10), new TernaryIntGeneric(5));
Console.WriteLine("10 / 5 = " + num10.integerValue);

00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000+0+0
Remainder: 0
Quotient: 30
High: 5
Low: -5
High Chosen
Remainder: 5
Quotient: 29
00000000000000000000000+--00000000000000000000000+0+-0
Remainder: 15
Quotient: 87
High: 20
Low: 10
High Chosen
Remainder: 20
Quotient: 86
0000000000000000000000+-+-0000000000000000000000+0+--0
Remainder: 60
Quotient: 258
High: 65
Low: 55
High Chosen
Remainder: 65
Quotient: 257

...

0000000000000000000+++-000++++++++++++++++++++++-0-++0
Remainder: 3079
Quotient: 3812798741871
High: 3084
Low: 3074
High Chosen
Remainder: 3084
Quotient: 3812798741870
10 / 5 = 3812798741870

Obviously, it's not dividing it just keeps getting bigger and bigger until an overflow happens.
